# Where is the Laplace transform an isomorphism?

Tags: laplace-transform

I have understand that the Fourier transform is an isomorphism between the Schwartz space.
Is the Laplace transform some isomorphism between some function space?

For example, I understand that if $f(z) $is an entire function of exponential type, its Laplace transform makes sense, but I don't know if this transform will end up in some space of functions where it can be inverted.

Thanks.